# How do I detect a shake event? I looked into react native shake but I noticed it only works on physical devices (I'm using xcode for iphone testing)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to set up shake detection in react-native using expo and I'm having difficulty finding out where to start. I've looked into using the accelerometer and gyroscope, but I don't know how to implement them for shake detection.

I've tried using the react-native-shake library, but that hasn't worked out too well.

Comment: A quick search on the Expo.io website turns up this [Snack example](https://snack.expo.io/rJwzj47Y4) that implements shake detection using this library: [rn-shake-move](https://github.com/ieschalier/rn-shake-move) whose source code is based off the `Accelerometer` module. Googling turns up other packages as well that implement this type of feature. Is there a particular thing you are stuck on?

Comment: Thanks Michael. This library works great. I've been trying to use other libraries, but they weren't reading the shake.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic concept example without external library. Adjust the update interval and sensibility to fit your need.

```js
import { Accelerometer } from "expo-sensors";

const configureShake = onShake => {
  // update value every 100ms.
  // Adjust this interval to detect
  // faster (20ms) or slower shakes (500ms)
  Accelerometer.setUpdateInterval(100);

  // at each update, we have acceleration registered on 3 axis
  // 1 = no device movement, only acceleration caused by gravity
  const onUpdate = ({ x, y, z }) => {

    // compute a total acceleration value, here with a square sum
    // you can eventually change the formula
    // if you want to prioritize an axis
    const acceleration = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

    // Adjust sensibility, because it can depend of usage (& devices)
    const sensibility = 1.8;
    if (acceleration >= sensibility) {
      onShake(acceleration);
    }
  };

  Accelerometer.addListener(onUpdate);
};

// usage :
const subscription = configureShake(acceleration => {
  console.log("shake with acceleration " + acceleration);
});

// when you're done, don't forget to unsubscribe
Accelerometer.removeAllListeners();
```

More on [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/accelerometer/)

Also, if shake is an important feature of your app, you should also give the ability to the user to adjust the sensibility because android phones have various sensor precision.

Comment: How to make this work in background? this is only when the app is open...